# No matching constructor error (Boost Beast, C++)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, initializer-list, boost-beast

Here's my header file for a WebSocket client:

```
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

class WebSocketClient {
 public:
  explicit WebSocketClient(asio::io_context &ioc);

 private:
  using stream_type = beast::websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>>;
  using ssl_context_type = asio::ssl::context;

  asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
  stream_type ws_;

  ssl_context_type get_ssl_context();
};
```

And here's my definition:

```
WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(asio::io_context &ioc)
    : resolver_(asio::make_strand(ioc)),
      ws_(asio::make_strand(ioc), get_ssl_context()) {
}

asio::ssl::context WebSocketClient::get_ssl_context() {
  return WebSocketClient::ssl_context_type(asio::ssl::context_base::tlsv12_client);
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
In template: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::basic_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::execution::context_as_t<boost::asio::execution_context &>, boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::never_t<0>, boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::possibly_t<0>>, boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::tracked_t<0>>, boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::untracked_t<0>>, boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::relationship::fork_t<0>>, boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::relationship::continuation_t<0>>>, boost::beast::unlimited_rate_policy>>' error occurred here in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::empty_::empty_value<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::basic_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::execution::context_as_t<boost::... in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::basic_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::execution::context_as_t<bo... in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::make_shared<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::basic_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::executi... in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::basic_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::execution::context_as_t<bo... candidate constructor template not viable: expects an l-value for 2nd argument candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
```

I'd be very grateful if somebody could explain why I'm getting this error? If I instead use the code below, and add another private member variable `ssl_context_` of type `ssl_context_type`, the error goes away, but I'm not really sure why... I'm quite new to C++.

```
WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(asio::io_context &ioc)
    : resolver_(asio::make_strand(ioc)),
      ssl_context_(asio::ssl::context_base::tlsv12_client),
      ws_(asio::make_strand(ioc), ssl_context_) {
}
```

Comment: is that the full error message? the compiler normally gives you some hints about what it doesn't like

Comment: I've updated to provide full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `boost::asio::ssl::stream` class constructor (and by induction, `beast::websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>>` constructor) requires an [l-value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of `boost::asio::ssl::context` as the second parameter, and `WebSocketClient::get_ssl_context` returns an [r-value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). In other words, `WebSocketClient::get_ssl_context` returns a temporary, which is not acceptable for `beast::websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>>`.

`ssl::context` needs to persist for the whole duration of the TLS stream, since the stream will be using the context during its operation. So the correct solution is to create an instance of `ssl::context` as a data member of `WebSocketClient` *before* `ws_` and provide a reference to it to `ws_` constructor.